# php maths loop query

Tags: php, math, loops

This will be hard to explain what I want, so I'll try my best.

I have a game, and the players in the game have a health counter (hp), and bodyguards as well. Each bodyguard has 100 hp, and once all a players bodyguards are gone, the damage comes off their hp.

So, these are the values I have:

```
$dmg // the damage
$bgs // the amount of bodyguards the player has
$bg_hp // the bodyguards health. Starts at 100, drains with $dmg fired at
$hp // the players health
```

When they're shot, it needs to check if they have $bgs. This is a basic example.

```
if ($bgs > 0) {
  $bgs_hp = $bgs_hp - $dmg;
     if ($bg_hp <= 0) { $bg = $bg - 1; $bg_hp = 100; }
  } else {
  $hp = $hp - $dmg;
  }
```

Anyway, the part I need help with is this. I want the damage to overlap.
So say the $dmg is 200, that would kill 2 bodyguards (they have 100 hp each). Or someone could shoot all their bodyguards and a remainder of the $dmg comes off the $hp too.

The reason I need help is because im awful at maths, and theres problem some MOD function or something that I need to use.

Examples;

1) Player has 3 bodyguards. Someone shoots at him for 150 dmg. It would kill 1 bodyguard, and cause 50 damage to the next.

2) Player has 1 bodyguard that is half hp (50). Someone shoots him for 160, it'd kill the bodyguard (50hp), and the rest of that damage (110) would kill the player too.

Comment: What if you have two bodyguards? can they take 200 dmg before your health will go down? Does $bg_hp contain the health of all bodyguards together or only of the one that is currently taking the bullets?

Comment: just the one that is taking the damage. the rest are at 100 and wont be touched until the 'top' one dies.

Comment: So if you have 2 bodyguards and take 199 damage, it kills 1 bodyguard but the other is unharmed, but if you take 201 damage it kills 2 bodyguards and the player gets 1 damage?

Comment: Nah, if you have 2 bodyguards and take 199 damage, it'll kill the first (100), then take 99 off the next, leaving it with 1 hp left.

Comment: @Juhana that's 201 not 199...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply retain an array with the hps of each bodyguard, like this:

```
$bgs = array(100); // one bg with 100 hp
```

or

```
$bgs = array(100, 300, 50); // one bg with 100 hp, then one with 300, etc
```

If you want to know how many bodyguards there are, a simple `count($bgs)` tells you.

This will make it much easier for you to expand your game in the future, and it also makes it much easier to resolve these types of calculations. You can now write:

```
$hp = 100;
$bgs = array(100, 100);
$damage = 101; // for example

// As long as there's still damage to take and bgs to take it:
while($damage && !empty($bgs)) {
    $soak = min($bgs[0], $damage); // not more than the first bg can take
    $bgs[0] -= $soak; // remove hps from the first bg
    $damage -= $soak; // deduct from the amount of damage to tage
    if ($bgs[0] == 0) {
        // bodyguard dead, remove him from the array
        array_shift($bgs);
    }
}

// If there's any damage left over, it goes to hp
$hp -= $damage;
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/CdAW3)**.

**Update:** Here's code that works with your current scheme. It's not really simpler, and it is more restrictive on what you can do:

```
$max_bg_health = 100;
$hp = 100;
$bgs = 2;
$bg_hp = $max_bg_health; // so that makes 2 "full health" bgs
$damage = 101; // for example
if($bgs) {
    $bg_capacity = ($bgs - 1) * $max_bg_health + $bg_hp;
    $soak = min($bg_capacity, $damage);
    $bg_capacity -= $soak;
    $damage -= $soak;

    // update bodyguard status; this is extra tricky because $bgs is not
    // "the amount of full hp bgs" (which would make it a lot simpler)
    // but "the amount of bgs including the one which may not have full hp"
    $bgs = $bg_capacity ? intval($bg_capacity - 1 / $max_bg_health) + 1 : 0;
    $bg_hp = $bg_capacity % $max_bg_health;
}

// If there's any damage left over, it goes to hp
$hp -= $damage;
```

Comment: thanks, i'll try and make sense of that (im still learning). If i used this I'd need to build the array based on my old method of having $bgs, $bgs_hp, and $hp since that's whats in use at the moment. Never really used arrays so i'll have to look into how they work.

Comment: @user961882: I updated the answer to cover your current case, but you should really go with the array.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is, to only store the total health points (i.e. yours and that of your bodyguards). You can then calculate your health points and the number of bodyguards from them everytime you need it (so you don't need to save them)

```
$totalhp = 499; // you have 100 health and 4 bodyguards, the last one has 99 health

$bgs = $totalhp > 100 ? (int)(($totalhp-1)/100) : 0; // Number of active bodyguards
$hp = min($totalhp, 100); // Your health
$bg_hp = $bgs > 0 ? ((($totalhp-1) % 100) + 1) : 0; // the health of your "current" bodyguard
```

Then, when you take some damage, simply subtract it from `$totalhp`:

```
$totalhp = $totalhp - $dmg;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$bg = 2;

$health_max = 100;

$health_total = $bg * $health_max + $health_max;

$damage = 100;

if($damage >= $health_total)
{
    die('You are caput.');
}
else
{
    $health_total = $health_total - $damage;
    $bg = floor($health_total / $health_max);
}

if($bg > 0)
{
    $tmp = ($health_total - $health_max) % $health_max;
    for($i = 1; $i < $bg; $i++)
        $bg_health[] = $health_max;
    $bg_health[] = $tmp;
    $bg_health = implode(', ', $bg_health);
}

if(empty($bg_health)) $tmp = 0;
$health = $health_total - $tmp;

echo "You have {$health} health and {$bg} bodyguards left with health of {$bg_health}.";
?>
```

This will produce...

> You have 100 health and 1 bodyguards left with health of 77.

Comment: If you set the damage to 100, the program will tell you that you have two bodyguards left (even if you only had two at the beginning).